# How can I receive two answers to one packet using scapy?

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I am developing something like TCP Server in Python using scapy.
A typical TCP server should work like this.

- First, it waits for an incoming SYN packet by calling `sniff`.
- Second, it sends a SYNACK and waits for an ACK response in a single call, this is done with `sr1` call.
- Third, it waits for an incoming packet with a client request by calling `sniff`.

But the problem is that request packet can arrive between the `sr1` and second `sniff` and thus get lost, because `sniff` does not capture packets that arrived before it is called.
(I can see with Wireshark that a packet is arriving).

How can I send SYNACK and receive both ACK and a request in one call, 'atomically'?

(In a typical TCP connection, the client will resend the packet with the request after some timeout, but according to the conditions of my task there is no re-sending of packets, packets cannot be lost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a scapy socket and call `sr1` or `sniff` on it. For instance

```
from scapy.config import conf
sock = conf.L3socket()
sock.sr1(....)
sock.sniff(...)
```

Because it is the same socket, you won't be losing any packets

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
But I would clarify that just creating a socket without parameters is not enough, it captures unwanted packets. I create a socket by specifying the type and filter:

    sock = linux.L3PacketSocket(type=ETH_P_IP, filter=f"tcp and dst host {src_ip} and dst port {src_port}")